# Cannot run a Grails Application on the Linux Server - Tomcat and H2 database

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, h2

I want to run a Grails application on Linux Server with embeded H2 database, Tomcat and Gradle. The specs are below

- Grails 2.4.4
- Groovy 2.3.7
- Gradle 2.2.1
- Tomcat 7.0.59
- Linux CentOS 6

The BuildConfig.groovy is like below

```
dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
}
plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

The Detasourece.groovy is below

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                }
        }
    }
}
```

with this config, I made a war file.

```
grails prod war
```

And then, I deployed a Grails application on a Linux server. Tomcat ran well. I could access http://myserver:8080. After that, I accessed http://myserver:8080/application/. As a result, it returned http code.

```
HTTP Status 404
```

I checked /etc/local/tomcat/log/stacktrace.log

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: 
Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Error opening database: "Could not save properties /prodDb.lock.db" [8000-176]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the permission issue, it is trying to create the file in root directory.

Try changing the datasource url in prod env to

```
 url = jdbc:h2:~/db/test;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
```

Comment: I add the permission to all files of the application, but I got same errors.  I run following command   #chmod 775 -R /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myApp

Comment: Even though, I do not understand why. I think it should be changed initially at the time grails application created.

Answer (score -1):

Another way I've used to get this to work -- if you don't need the database persisted on disk -- is to put the production database into memory like this:

```
url = jdbc:h2:mem:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
```

This is not dependent on ANY disk permissions on the server (e.g. a production environment where you don't even have an account, so "~/" wouldn't be a valid directory.)